# box-shadow is not follow the z-index sequence

Tags: html, css

i have issue on box-shadow is not follow the div.

i set the z-index but still not working, please help.

box-shadow is always behind the pseudo class

below here is the html code:

```
<div class="img-holder sub-images">
<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80589894/mobileUI/images/flash0.png" />
                        <div class="back-image"></div>
                    </div>
```

css:

```
.img-holder{
width:80px;
height:71px;
position: relative;
z-index:1;
text-align: center;
margin:10px 15px;
border:solid 3px #fff;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.66);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.66);
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.66);
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

```
.img-holder img{
cursor:pointer;
max-width:100%;
```

}

```
.sub-images:after{
content: " ";
background:url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80589894/mobileUI/images/cat-blank-bg.jpg) top center no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position: absolute; 
z-index:-1;
border:solid 3px #fff;
top:-3px;
left: -3px;
top:0px \9;/* IE 9 */
left: 0px \9;/* IE 9 */
-ms-transform:rotate(-10deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
transform: rotate(-10deg);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.66);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.66);
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.66);
```

}

check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/3WuST/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap some of the CSS around in `.img-holder` and `.img-holder img`. See http://jsfiddle.net/3WuST/1/

Comment: Thanks luke. Can you explain why i can't set the rule on the .img-holder div?

Comment: I just found out that removing the z-index from `.img-holder` makes it work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3WuST/2/

Comment: I was removing z-index from .img-holder before i post here. It doesn't work for me, But your swap method work for me. I just don't understand why set the css rule on parent div didn't work, instead need to set css rules on img. Anyway thanks for your help.